# how to display django form field in template withou value?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django form, with values initialized.But i dont want the values to be displayed to the user.I am using {{formobject.fieldname}} in template but it displays the value too.Is there any option to hide the field value alone?

Comment: Why would you want to initialize a form with values but not show the values to the user?

Comment: I will display the values at the top of the page.If the user wishes to edit the values(selects change address radio button), i will show these input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise a second, unbound form in your view,

```
blank_form = MyForm()
```

then use this form to render your blank fields in the template.

```
{{ blank_form.fieldname }}
```

Comment: Yeah! this is good. But it seems to be a workaround,is there an option in forms itself to decide whether to show/hide values?

Comment: No, I don't think there isn't any option that hides the values. You want to display an empty form, so I think it's better to explicitly create an unbound form without an instance, rather than trying to hide the values.